# Clustered WSO2IS with cert on the load balancer?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

All of the WSO2IS documentation I have seen describes how to configure a cluster with the SSL terminated on each host.  Is it possible, or even advisable, to configure the SSL cert on the load balancer?  I believe the SSL cert still needs to be installed in the primary keystore on each cluster host because that cert is used for more than just web SSL encryption.  We are using a separate internal keystore for data encipherment.  I'm not that familiar with the internal workings of WOS2IS so I can't determine if there is a requirement to have the SSL terminate on each cluster host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking to achieve is described in [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+TLS+Termination) and [this](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/administer/configuring-tls-termination/) documentation.

But I would suggest against completely disabling SSL at the LB level since someone who has access to the internal network can view data in plain text. Instead what you can do is terminate SSL from the load balancer from the LB level and start a new SSL connection between LB and each Identity Server node.